# Calling ScriptManager from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext, scriptmanager

I'm trying to execute a javascript function from a C# class in an asp.net application. I'm using the `ScriptManager`. I have a class `UpdateUI`, which contains the following method:

```
public static void RunScript()
{
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            Page currentPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(currentPage, currentPage.GetType(), "disableControls", "disableControls()", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

When I call `UpdateUI.RunScript()` from another static class, the `HttpContent.Current` is `null`. Any idea how should I go in order to be able to execute the scriptmanager from a class which is not code-behind?

Comment: From where does the static class call this method? During a page's lifecycle? Otherwise it is `null` (e.g. from a webmethod).

Comment: @TimSchmelter As far as I know in a WebMethod HttpContext.Current is available. I think I already did this to get Session data in a WebMethod.

Comment: @VitorCanova: As far as i know `HttpContext.Current.Handler` is not a `Page` in a webmethod so it's `null`. However, it was just an example. He has not mentioned if the static class is used during the lifecycle of a page.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree. I mention that because Krafo said that `HttpContext.Current` is `null`, not the `Hanlder` part. This fact is strange to me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the HttpContext to the method within your static class. As Tim Schmelter's comment indicates, calling HttpContext.Current will fail if it's not done in response to an incoming request.

```
public static void RunScript(HttpContext context);
```